# Sort, calculate and then mutate in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a beginner in R and I'm facing an issue.

Problem: I need to sort a dataframe by 2 columns (ID, i'th column) and then take lagged difference of the i'th column and record it. Then resort the data with the ID and the i+1 column and so on and so forth.

What I have written up till now:

```
for (val in (4:length(colnames(df)))){
    df <- df[with(df, order(ID, df[val])), ]
    d2_df <- df %>% 
      mutate_at(c(df[val]), list(lagged = ~ . - lag(.)))
  }
```

The above code is messing somehow because the mutate_at function is throwing the error below:

```
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a list.
```

Original dataset:

```
  ID S1 S2
1 1  3  1
2 1  5  2
3 1  1  3
4 2  2  7
5 3  4  9
6 3  2  11
```

After Sort on ID and S1

```
  ID S1 S2
1 1  1  3
2 1  3  1
3 1  5  2
4 2  2  7
5 3  2  11
6 3  4  9
```

Now what I need? S1.1 (which is the lagged difference of the sorted dataframe respective to each ID)

```
  ID S1 S2 S1.1
1 1  1  3  NA
2 1  3  1  2
3 1  5  2  2
4 2  2  7  NA
5 3  2  11 NA
6 3  4  9  2
```

Similar logic applies for S2 where a new S2.2 will be generated.
Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Additionally what is required (below); where sum.S1 is the sum of the lagged differences and count.S1 is the count of observations at S1 for respective ID:

```
  ID sum.S1 sum.S2 count.S1 count.S2
1 1  4      2      3        3
2 2  NA     NA     1        1
3 3  2      2      2        2
```

Comment: please share a reproducible example along with expected outcome.

Comment: Added an example and the outcome as requested.

Comment: Do you want NA or 0 when the difference is zero?

Comment: So would you have multiple dataframes as output? Or you want to keep on adding new columns?

Comment: So basically you need `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(S1) %>% mutate(S1_1 = cumsum(S1))`

Comment: When the difference is 0, it should be zero. Just an additional that S1 and S2 also contains NA's in the original dataset.

Comment: @RonakShah in essence, I need a single dataframe with the lagged differences. I seem to have problems in using cbind.

Comment: @Sotos, Is there a way to iterate through? Because I need differences for S1, S2 and so on.. after each sort.

Comment: Maybe `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange_all() %>% mutate_all(list(~. - lag(.)))`? But it only sorts once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using non-standard evaluation (NSE) :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

cols <- c('S1', 'S2')
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(cols, ~{
     col <- sym(.x)
     df %>% 
       arrange(ID, !!col) %>%
       group_by(ID) %>%
       transmute(!!paste0(.x, '.1') := !!col - lag(!!col)) %>%
       ungroup %>%
       select(-ID)
 }))


#  ID S1 S2 S1.1 S2.1
#1  1  3  1   NA   NA
#2  1  5  2    2    1
#3  1  1  3    2    1
#4  2  2  7   NA   NA
#5  3  4  9   NA   NA
#6  3  2 11    2    2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), S1 = c(3L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 2L), S2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 11L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can this account for NA's in S1 and S2? I've tried this relentlessly after fixing my data type and class and its still throwing me an error:  Error in !col : invalid argument type

Comment: It should work with `NA`'s as well and return `NA`. Can you check with the data provided in my answer (which is similar to what you have shown) and see if it works for you? If it does then you need to provide your data similarly in reproducible format so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I just tried on the datastructure that you posted and its still giving me the error:  Error in !col : invalid argument type . A bit strange. Could you recheck on your end.

Comment: That is weird because I just tried on the fresh R session and it works fine for me. Maybe there is a package mismatch. What are the package versions that you have. I have `packageVersion('dplyr')`, `[1] ‘1.0.0’`, `packageVersion('purrr')`, `[1] ‘0.3.4’` and `packageVersion('rlang') [1] ‘0.4.6’`. If you have any older version of package try updating it to latest version.

Comment: My packages were outdated. Worked perfectly. Is there any way to calculate the sum and count of each lagged difference per group id? For example: ID 1: S1.1.sum is 4 and count is 3. Is there a way to make that sort of a dataframe within this formulation. Because the ID gets a mismatch after each sort.

Comment: Maybe after `transmute` you can add `summarise(total = sum(!!col, na.rm = TRUE), n = n())` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, sorry to bug you again but this method keeps throwing an error. Is there a way to do the same process in dplyr version 1.0.1.

Comment: The ID column is a string in the original dataset. Not sure if that would throw an error.

Comment: That is strange. What error does it give? I don't see how anything in `dplyr` 1.0.1 would change this. It doesn't matter if `ID` column is character.